# How do I disable dropzone's automatic file upload?

Tags: javascript, file-upload, dropzone.js

I want to use dropzone to allow users to drag and drop file in, but I don't want dropzone to actually upload the files at any point. How do I disable this functionality in dropzone?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Check out the [autoProcessQueue](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-autoProcessQueue) setting in dropzone config

> When set to false you have to call myDropzone.processQueue() yourself in order to upload the dropped files.

Comment: How do you do that for an auto-initialized <form> ?